# Use reflection to make dynamic LINQ statements in C#

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

If I have a LINQ statement like

```
x = Table.SingleOrDefault(o => o.id == 1).o.name;
```

how can I replace "id" and "name" with passed in variables using reflection? I keep getting object reference not set to instance of an object errors when I try. My attempts are things like

```
x = (string)Table.SingleOrDefault(o => (int?)o.GetType().GetProperty(idString)
.GetValue(o, null) == 1).GetType().GetField(nameString).GetValue(x);
```

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I could not understand your problem or even your code :(. Could you remake the question body?

Comment: what is p  in GetValue ?

Comment: a typo. should be o. Will edit.

Comment: What kind of LINQ is it? LINQ to Objects, LINQ to Entities, LINQ to SQL?

Comment: Try to specify `BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public` as binding flags

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You should use Expression Trees instead of reflection. It will perform better, and you'll be able to use it with both LINQ to Objects and LINQ to SQL/Entities.

```
var source = new List<Test> { new Test { Id = 1, Name = "FirsT" }, new Test { Id = 2, Name = "Second" } };
var idName = "Id";
var idValue = 1;

var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Test));
var condition =
    Expression.Lambda<Func<Test, bool>>(
        Expression.Equal(
            Expression.Property(param, idName),
            Expression.Constant(idValue, typeof(int))
        ),
        param
    ).Compile(); // for LINQ to SQl/Entities skip Compile() call

var item = source.SingleOrDefault(condition);
```

then, you can get `Name` property using reflection (you'll do it just once, so it's fine to do it using reflection.

```
var nameName = "Name";
var name = item == null ? null : (string) typeof(Test).GetProperty(nameName).GetValue(item);
```

`Test` class is defined as

```
public class Test
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This works great. Just a tiny tweak to the code and it does what I wanted. Thank you.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek This is EXACTLY what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use reflection, but you can use dynamic Linq as described [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx).  If you are using Entity Framework for this, you should also be able to use Entity SQL, which is basically a hard-coded SQL string.

Comment: Maybe he could rewrite the lambda using expressions. But I am not sure of that he needs.