# Converting VB to C# with Linq and Reflection

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, reflection

I'm working on a project converting some VB to C#.  This particular Linq query works fine in VB, but it's giving me fits trying to convert.

The C# piece that I'm struggling with is the group by
`prop.GetProperty(stringColumn).GetValue(s, null).ToString()`
The compiler error is

> Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

It also notes that the `s` variable in the `select` does not exist.

**VB**

```
(From s In query Group By StringValue = 
    prop.GetProperty(stringColumn).GetValue(s, Nothing)
          Into NumTotal =
          Sum(Double.Parse(prop.GetProperty(numberColumn).GetValue(s, Nothing).ToString()))
          Order By NumTotal Descending Select StringValue, NumTotal)
```

**C#**

```
(from s in query group s by 
 new {prop.GetProperty(stringColumn).GetValue(s, null).ToString()} into NumTotal
    select new {
        StringValue = prop.GetProperty(stringColumn).GetValue(s, null),
        NumTotal = NumTotal.Sum(x =>
            Double.Parse(prop.GetProperty(numberColumn).GetValue(s, null).ToString()))})
```

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23814949/use-reflection-to-make-dynamic-linq-statements-in-c-sharp), but I really didn't understand how the `Expression` stuff was supposed to work, and wasn't sure if it should be part of my solution. 
What am I missing in the conversion, and why would two seemingly similar queries behave so differently?

Thanks

Comment: The error possibly refers to your grouping operator (you tried creating a new object with just a value and no field name)... try `group s by new { PropValue = prop.GetProperty(stringColumn).GetValue(s, Nothing) }` ... and the way you are grouping will require some changes.  See https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-to-DataSets-Grouping-c62703ea